# Tailwind CSS not working in react-native-web

Tags: react-native, tailwind-css, react-native-web

[image: enter image There]

This is how my login screen looks on web however on iOS it looks like this
[image]

Any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking around on Google, I came across this response from github

https://github.com/kristerkari/react-native-css-modules/issues/37#issuecomment-1269678996